# JavaFX Stage width issue on different resolutions

Tags: javafx

I made a JavaFX application on my PC and I fixed its size. When I built it on my Macbook, the window was distorted, I had to increase width to make it look ok again. It didn't reach the laptop bounds, so its not an issue of not enough pixels. Can someone tell me what is the problem here and how can I make the fixed size look the same on all resolutions? Thank you.

Edit:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Pane root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));

    initializeStuff();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title comes here");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Root panel:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" stylesheets="/sample/style.css" fx:controller="sample.mainController">
    <fx:include source="/sample/menubar/MenuBar.fxml" fx:id="menuBar"/>

</VBox>
```

Comment: Provide some code: your `.fxml` file, the code that opens it, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not every screen has the same [Pixel Density.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) You define your scene to be `800x800` and disable the resizing. That might be ok for your PC, but your Macbook has a different `pixel density`, which basically means you have more/less pixels per inch on that monitor.

I had the same problem with an application before. Also made size static and disabled resizing. But when using it from `Windows 7` to `Windows 8` on another laptop, it was completely distorted.

The solution is trying to use your layouts optimally. Don't lay out everything statically and define pixel margins. Use `JavaFX's` provided layouts and play around with their `min/preferred/max height/width` properties.